# install and Run Kurento Media server in Cent OS 6.6 using Docker

Tags: centos, docker, webrtc, ubuntu-10.04, kurento

I need to install and run Kurento Media Server in a Cent OS to use it for Large Scale Webrtc Application for one to many conferences .

I heard that it can be done through Docker.

So if some can guide me through the steps to do so I will be thankful.

But if you know some other way to install and run Kurento Media Server in Cent OS
then that is fine with me.

Comment: Just improved a bit of language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find several examples in the Docker Hub, see https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=kurento&searchfield= and some examples 
so you can get one, issue a `docker history` to see what commands were used to build (and some `docker inspect` on each layer), or simply use https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image to generate the associated Dockerfile

Comment: I've tried some of these as well as writing my own Dockerfile for KMS. I get the same result from all of them. Everything seems to start up and I have no errors, but when I run any examples, the remote stream doesn't work. The server console says "sending candidate" and nothing else happens. If I install KMS on my actual machine rather than docker, it works fine. Could you show what image you use and what command you use to run it that works? Perhaps there's a port or setting I'm leaving out?

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile and the error message you get?

Comment: For example, using `irian/kurento` or `kurento/media-server-64` images, then using `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 the-image` and starting up the node server from any of the examples, there is no error. It seems to find the media server. There's some `Queuing candidate` and then `Sending candidate` messages logged, and then it just hangs on `Sending candidate`. Nothing happens after that.

Comment: I may have gotten it! Adding the `--net=host` flag seems to be the key.